# How to add existing user interfaces and class to one project in visual studio 2008 c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

our group project(TransactionManager) need to get together(combine)  one project 
stock management ,customer management ,supplier management ,invoice build by separately
finally we need to combine each project as one project when we add existing item to visual studio it's give errors do not show user interfaces after adding.
we are student please help us our group project

following error

To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

(The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: frmItem --- The base class 'TransactionManager.AppBaseForm.frmBaseF… could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built )

Comment: Add a bit more on the error message you get.

Comment: One project, or one solution?  Usually I'd handle this by combining them into one solution.  Unless the absolutely have to be in the same DLL, it's best to ship them separately.  This has the added advantage of being able to limit bug fixes to individual assemblies (so you only have to test the product that has the fix), and allowing you to version them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go a little bit out on a limb here because I'm not sure there's enough information to know exactly what is causing the problem, but I've seen this something similar to this before.

The first thing I would do is check and see if your base form (looks like frmBaseForm) is declared as abstract. Visual Studio cannot load forms into the designer if they are declared as abstract because the designer tries to create an instance of the base class, which it cannot do.

If you find that this is the case with your project, the only solution that I know of is removing the abstract designation on the base form.

(See this thread on the MSDN forums for more information: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/afdfce40-8d7a-4300-bd8d-26e18c320a71)

Additionally, check that you have a parameterless constructor for the base form that your other forms inherit from. Likewise, the designer always tries to call the parameterless constructor to instantiate the form during design time, and if this doesn't exist, the designer will fail. To fix this, you can simply add an overload to the constructors on your base form that requires no parameters.

Finally, ensure that the base form (again, it looks like in your case this is called frmBaseForm) has been added to the new project. The error message is telling you where this form can be found. The form you are trying to open in the designer derives from that base form, and if you haven't moved the base form into the new project, the designer might be unable to find it. If you've ensured that the base form does appear in the new combined project, make sure that you build the project before trying to re-open the designer.